# Android auto inject dagger modules on each of i need that

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

After successful implementing Dagger on project i have to specify dagger to each of class i want to use and inject modules, for example `RestClient` of `retrofit`, i want to know is any way to define automatically `components` into classes?

for example my implementation is:

```
public class CoreApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    private static ProjectApplicationComponent component;
    private RestClient restClient;
    private Picasso picasso;
    private Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ...
        component = DaggerProjectApplicationComponent.builder()
                .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
                .networkServiceModule(new NetworkServiceModule(ClientSettings.SERVER_URL))
                .build();

        restClient= component.apiService();
        picasso = component.getPicasso();
        handler = component.getHandler();
    }

    public static ProjectApplicationComponent getComponent() {
        return component;
    }
}
```

and my `ApplicationComponent` which i define witch class or activity or fragment i want to inject modules:

```
@ActivitiesScope
@Component(dependencies = ProjectApplicationComponent.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(PersonsRemoteRepository personsRemoteRepository);
}
```

and `PersonsRemoteRepository` class which i want to inject `RestClient` to use Retrofit

```
public class PersonsRemoteRepository implements PersonsRepository {
    @Inject
    private RestClient restClient;

    private final ApplicationComponent component;

    public PersonsRemoteRepository() {
        component = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .projectApplicationComponent(CoreApplication.getComponent())
                .build();

        component.inject(this);
    }

    ...
}
```

my `RestClient` class is:

```
public interface RestClient {
    @Headers("Content-Type: application/json")
    @POST("/api/v1/getPersons")
    Observable<List<Person>> getPersons();
}
```

my mean is removing `component` and `component.inject(this);` from all of classes that i want to inject `RestClient`

```
@Inject
private RestClient restClient;
```

for example simplified `PersonsRemoteRepository` class should be:

```
public class PersonsRemoteRepository implements PersonsRepository {
    @Inject
    private RestClient restClient;

    public PersonsRemoteRepository() {

    }

    ...
}
```

Thanks in advance

---

**UPDATE POST**

in this my activity `inject(this)` is not available on this line of code:

```
CoreApplication.getComponent().inject(this);
```

My activity:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    @Inject
    PersonsRemoteRepository personsRemoteRepository;

    @Inject
    RestClient restClient;

    private LoginActivityBinding mBinding;
    private LoginMethodsToPageViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CoreApplication.getComponent().inject(this);

        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.login_activity);

        personsRemoteRepository = new PersonsRemoteRepository(restClient);
        viewModel = new LoginMethodsToPageViewModel(personsRemoteRepository, this, mBinding);
        mBinding.setViewModel(viewModel);
    }

    ...
}
```

in this screen shot as you see i dont have `inject()` method

[image]

`PersonsRemoteRepository` class after change:

```
public class PersonsRemoteRepository implements PersonsRepository {
    private RestClient restClient;

    @Inject
    PersonsRemoteRepository(RestClient restClient) {
        this.restClient = restClient;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    public Observable<List<Person>> getAllPersons() {
        Observable<List<Person>> observable = restClient.getPersons();

        return observable
                .flatMap((Function<List<Person>, Observable<List<Person>>>) Observable::fromArray);
    }
}
```

Comment: Whaaaaaat? Why are you creating a new Component instance in ***the constructor of every injection point***? You should create only one, inside Application, and use *that*, combined with `@Inject` constructor

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i try to fix this implementation

Comment: Although now that I read it again and with more detail, my *real* question is, "why do you need `ApplicationComponent` on top of `ProjectApplicationComponent`".

Comment: @EpicPandaForce i just learn dagger2 and i can only  implementing that, i'm not sure why i need

Comment: Then you should probably just remove `ApplicationComponent`, and use `ProjectApplicationComponent`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce your mean is removing `ApplicationComponent` interface file?

Comment: Yes. Just remove it, because you don't need it.

Comment: ok, how abou automatically inject without specify in all of classes which i want to use injection?

Comment: just use constructor injection

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two questions, how to inject into `CoreApplication` and how to inject into activities. And there are two corresponding components, `ProjectApplicationComponent` and `ApplicationComponent`, connected by component dependency.

---

To Inject into the application, the answer from Gustavo is useful:

- Annotate fields of `CoreApplication` as `@Inject`,
- Replace provision methods in `ProjectApplicationComponent` with a members-injection method:

  ```java
  @ApplicationScope
  @Component(
          modules = {
              ContextModule.class,
              NetworkServiceModule.class,
              ...,
          })
  public interface ProjectApplicationComponent {
      // Members-injection method
      void inject(CoreApplication coreApplication);
  }
  ```
- Construct a `ProjectApplicationComponent` and call the `inject` method:

  ```java
  // CoreApplication.onCreate
  component =
      DaggerProjectApplicationComponent.builder()
          .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
          .networkServiceModule(...)
          .build();
  component.inject(/* coreApplication= */ this);
  ```

---

To inject into `LoginActivity`, the depending `ApplicationComponent` should have a members-injection method:

```java
@ActivitiesScope
@Component(dependencies = ProjectApplicationComponent.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(LoginActivity loginActivity);
}
```

Recall that your `LoginActivity` has two `@Inject`ed fields, with types `RestClient` and `PersonsRemoteRepository`.

```java
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject PersonsRemoteRepository personsRemoteRepository;
    @Inject RestClient restClient;
}
```

In order for the depending `ApplicationComponent` to obtain a `RestClient`, the depended `ProjectApplicationComponent` should expose a provision method:

```java
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {...})
public interface ProjectApplicationComponent {
    // Members-injection method
    void inject(CoreApplication coreApplication);

    // Provision method
    RestClient getRestClient();
}
```

For `PersonsRemoteRepository`, Dagger can construct one using constructor injection:

```java
// May be scoped @ActivitiesScope, or not
public class PersonsRemoteRepository implements PersonsRepository {
    private final RestClient restClient;

    @Inject
    PersonsRemoteRepository(RestClient restClient) {
        this.restClient = restClient;
    }
}
```

Then when you create your `LoginActivity`, build the Dagger-generated component as follows:

```java
// LoginActivity.onCreate
ApplicationComponent component =
    DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
        .projectApplicationComponent(CoreApplication.getComponent())
        .build();
component.inject(/* loginActivity= */ this);
```

Comment: i get error when i re-build prject after change classes  `ProjectApplicationComponent scoped with @Singleton may not reference bindings with different scopes` http://paste.debian.net/1077582/ AND my `ProjectApplicationComponent` content is http://paste.debian.net/1077584/

Comment: At the first glance you are using `@ApplicationScope` where I am using `@Singleton`, which is not a huge problem. Just replace my `@Singleton` with your `@ApplicationScope`.

Comment: @peterway i ger this error now `cannot find symbol DaggerProjectApplicationComponent.builder()` and i can't import that, this is unknown

Comment: @DolDurma From your last error log and last `ProjectApplicationComponent` interface definition, there are two provision methods that returns `RestClient` and so "RestClient is bound multiple times". Just keep one of them; the method name does not matter to Dagger.

Comment: unfortunately you comment is not clear for me how can i resolve that

Comment: @DolDurma Here in your last `ProjectApplicationComponent` http://paste.debian.net/1077584/, both `getRestClient()` and `apiService()` return `RestClient`. That's why Dagger complains that "RestClient is bound multiple times". Remove one and keep the other.

Comment: I'm so sorry i changed that to http://paste.debian.net/1077588/ a few minutes ago, and i wneh i re-build project i get `cannot find symbol DaggerProjectApplicationComponent.builder()` error , i paste all class into this link http://paste.debian.net/1077589/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191817/discussion-between-doldurma-and-peterwhy).

Comment: Hi @DolDurma, is there anything else that I can help on top of this answer?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to build your component for every class that you want to inject dependencies. The dependencies can be provided via constructor annotated with `@Inject`:

```java
public class PersonsRemoteRepository implements PersonsRepository {

    private RestClient restClient;

    @Inject
    public PersonsRemoteRepository(RestClient restClient) {
         this.restClient = restClient;
    }
}
```

And any other class that needs this repository can do the same:

```java
public class AnyOtherClass {
    private PersonsRemoteRepository personsRemoteRepository;

    @Inject
    public AnyOtherClass(PersonsRemoteRepository personsRemoteRepository) {
        this.personsRemoteRepository = personsRemoteRepository;
    }
```

You only need to use `component.inject` for classes that instances are created by Android, like Application, Activities and Fragments.

```java
public class MyActivity {
    @Inject PersonsRemoteRepository personsRemoteRepository;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        CoreApplication.getComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```

Changes needed in your CoreApplication:

```
public class CoreApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    private static ProjectApplicationComponent component;

    @Inject private RestClient restClient;
    @Inject private Picasso picasso;
    @Inject private Handler handler;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        ...
        component = DaggerProjectApplicationComponent.builder()
                .contextModule(new ContextModule(this))
                .networkServiceModule(new NetworkServiceModule(ClientSettings.SERVER_URL))
                .build();

        component.inject(this);
    }
}
```

Changes needed in your ApplicationComponent:

```
@ActivitiesScope
@Component(dependencies = ProjectApplicationComponent.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    void inject(CoreApplication coreApplication);

    void inject(MyActivity myActivity);
}
```

Comment: Since OP uses component dependency, the inject code inside `MyActivity.onCreate()` is more like

```java
DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
    .projectApplicationComponent(CoreApplication.getComponent())
    .build()
    .inject(/* myActivity= */ this);
```

Comment: @Gustavo `inject` is not available in `CoreApplication.getComponent().inject(this);` I'm not sure my change is correct, then i update my post Thanks

Comment: @peterwhy yes you are righ. my code updated, i dont have inject method